# get fullName without path

Tags: c#

I need to enter part of a file name (myTestFiles)
And I need to retrieve (myTestFiles_20210305.txt)
For now I am recovering (C: \ folder1 \ folder2 \ myTestFiles_20210305.txt)

For the moment with my order I get the name of the file AND THE PATH, which I do not want.

I just want to get the name of the file.
and why not the path but on two different exploitable variables.

I am a beginner on this language and on the forums that I have used I only saw what I already had ...

Thank you

Code:

```
        string partialName = "myTestFiles";
        DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new 
        DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Alexandre.boyere\Desktop\test\");

        FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + partialName + "*.*");

        foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
        {
            string fullName = foundFile.FullName;
            MessageBox.Show(fullName); 
        }
```

Comment: You want to use .Name instead of .FullName i beleive - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.name?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the file name from the path, use Path.GetFileName method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=net-5.0

Example code from documentation:

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'",
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'",
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following:
//
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile.ext'
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```